# Using the right exception subclass in ruby

Tags: ruby, exception

I have access to ruby's exception hierarchy (it's mentioned in both the pickaxe and the hummingbird), but I'm not sure which exception to use because I haven't found any information on what each of the terms mean.

Does using the right exception class matter?

Comment: Just came across a description of the exception classes at http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby/wiki/ExceptionClassesDoc

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"It depends".

One of the main problems with Ruby is the lack of good specification. It used to be worse, though.

This is mainly a question of style: If your error can be described well with one of the builtin exception classes, use it. If you think a subclass makes sense, use it.

Otherwise, you could consider to follow [this lead from a C++ coding standard](http://www.possibility.com/Cpp/CppCodingStandard.html#coeeal):

> Creating very elaborate exception
>   hierarchies is a waste of time. Nobody
>   ends of caring and all the effort goes
>   to waste. Instead, create one
>   exception per library or namespace and
>   have an exception reason within that
>   exception to indicate the type of the
>   exception.
>
> For example, for your OS encapsulation
>   libary, make an exception called
>   OsencapException.

Comment: Instead of creating one exception per library, I would suggest creating one exception for each condition you want to catch. You may use a RuntimeError by default, and when you detect that you think about parsing the error message in a rescue block, create a new class.

Answer (score 10):

It matters when creating your own exceptions. One important caveat is that exceptions which inherit from Exception rather then StandardError (common mistake) will not be caught by rescue (without any arguments).

Comment: This means that any Exception class you make should always inherit from StandardError, never directly from Exception.  I think you could have made this a bit clearer...

Answer (score 1):

No.

Or rather, if it doesn't matter to you, it generally doesn't matter to anyone else.  If you are writing a library, you should use something the users of your library will understand, but that's about it.