# Best practice: Using system supplied or custom exceptions for error conditions in ruby?

Tags: ruby, exception

Writing a rather simple command line tool in ruby I need to report meaningful messages on errors in the command line arguments, or for that matter other error conditions in the program. (Input file not found, invalid format of input etc)

For now I just raise ArgumentError with a sensible description when detecting errors in the argument list. Is this good practice, or do I risk hiding programming errors as well with this approach? In other words, are the system defined exceptions in ruby meant for application usage, or should we always create our own exceptions for reporting non-system errors?

**Edit:**
As an example, ruby raises ArgumentError if I call a method with the wrong number of arguments. This is a programming error that I want to be told about with stack traces and all. However when input to my program is incorrect I may want to give a brief message to the user, or even ignore it silently. This suggests to me that ArgumentError is not suitable for the applications own use.

Comment: Related question: [Using the right exception subclass in ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/699372/using-the-right-exception-subclass-in-ruby)

Comment: Andrew, thanks I missed that one.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe the best practice is to raise your own custom error, namespaced in a module. All of your specific exception classes should inherit from one namespaced exception that inherits from StandardError. So for your case:

```
module MyApp
  class Error < StandardError; end
  class ArgumentError < Error; end
end
```

and raise MyApp::ArgumentError when the user provides bad arguments. That way it differentiates from an argument error in your code. And you can rescue any uncaught exception from your app at a high level with MyApp::Error.

You should also check out [Thor](https://github.com/wycats/thor). It can handle most of the user argument stuff for you. You can look at [Bundler](https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler) for a good cli usage example.

Answer (score 28):

The Ruby 1.9 exception hierarchy is as follows:

```
Exception
+- NoMemoryError
+- ScriptError
|  +- LoadError
|  +- NotImplementedError
|  +- SyntaxError
+- SignalException
|  +- Interrupt
+- StandardError
|  +- ArgumentError
|  +- IOError
|  |  +- EOFError
|  +- IndexError
|  +- LocalJumpError
|  +- NameError
|  |  +- NoMethodError
|  +- RangeError
|  |  +- FloatDomainError
|  +- RegexpError
|  +- RuntimeError
|  +- SecurityError
|  +- SystemCallError
|  +- SystemStackError
|  +- ThreadError
|  +- TypeError
|  +- ZeroDivisionError
+- SystemExit
+- fatal
```

The Ruby 2 exception hierarchy is:

```
Exception
+- NoMemoryError
+- ScriptError
|  +- LoadError
|  +- NotImplementedError
|  +- SyntaxError
+- SecurityError
+- SignalException
|  +- Interrupt
+- StandardError # default for rescue
|  +- ArgumentError
|  |  +- UncaughtThrowError
|  +- EncodingError
|  +- FiberError
|  +- IOError
|  |  +- EOFError
|  +- IndexError
|  |  +- KeyError
|  |  +- StopIteration
|  +- LocalJumpError
|  +- NameError
|  |  +- NoMethodError
|  +- RangeError
|  |  +- FloatDomainError
|  +- RegexpError
|  +- RuntimeError # default for raise
|  +- SystemCallError
|  |  +- Errno::*
|  +- ThreadError
|  +- TypeError
|  +- ZeroDivisionError
+- SystemExit
+- SystemStackError
+- fatal # impossible to rescue
```

You can use one of these, as you have, or create your own. When creating your own, there are a couple of things to note. For one, `rescue` by default only rescues `StandardError` and its descendants. I found this out the hard way. It's best to make sure your custom errors inherit from `StandardError`. (By the way, to rescue any exception, use `rescue Exception` explicitly.)

You *can* create an exception class complete with attributes, custom constructors, etc. but standard practice is to just create simple definitions:

```
class ProcessingError < RuntimeError; end
```

You can differentiate specific errors with different error messages, or create a hierarchy of errors. Creating *elaborate* exception hierarchies is generally not done, or at least I've not seen an example of it (and I tend to read the source of libraries I use). What I have seen is the use of a Module to namespace your errors, which I think is a good idea.

```
module MyLibrary
  class Error < StandardError; end
  class ConnectionError < Error; end
end
```

Then your exceptions will be of the form `MyLibrary::ConnectionError` and to rescue errors from your library specifically you can `rescue MyLibrary::Error` and catch them all.

Note: an alternative syntax is `MyError = Class.new(RuntimeError)` see the reference to Steve Klabnik's blog post below.

References:

- [Ruby's Exception Hierarchy](http://blog.nicksieger.com/articles/2006/09/06/rubys-exception-hierarchy) by Nick Sieger.
- [Raising the Right Exception](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2007/3/7/raising-the-right-exception) by Jamis Buck.
- [Random Ruby Tricks: Class.new](http://blog.steveklabnik.com/posts/2012-09-09-random-ruby-tricks--class-new) by Steve Klabnik.

A fantastic read:
   [Exceptional Ruby](http://exceptionalruby.com/) by Avdi Grimm

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of the exception hierarchy, but I'm unsure about the correct usage of it. The bucklogs reference was very insightful, though! I've updated the question a bit to hopefully make my concerns a bit clearer.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's One True Way; as this isn't Python :). I've seen code use the built-in exceptions, and I've seen code use custom ones. As I implied, my preference is to use Module-scoped descendants of StandardError.

Comment: Rather than use `class MyError < StandardError; end`, Steve Klabnik recently in [his blog](http://blog.steveklabnik.com/posts/2012-09-09-random-ruby-tricks--class-new) notes that you can use `MyError = Class.new(StandardError)` which is actually quite nice, though not seen in Ruby code in the wild very much.

Comment: I love how thorough this explanation is.  Thanks Mark.

Comment: I don't believe `SecurityError` is of type `StandardError`

Comment: I commonly see custom exceptions inheriting from either `StandardError` or `RuntimeError` (in both cases `StandardError` is an ancestor). This answer also includes examples of inheriting from both. To make it clear to readers when to inherit from which, keep in mind that they are both generic error classes, but `RuntimeError` is for when an invalid operation is attempted. However, in practice it won't make much of a difference which you inherit from.

Comment: @lebreeze It appears that it is different in Ruby 2. I'll update the post.